# how to create a elastic watch which can identify the changes of data in a given index of elasticsearch

Tags: watch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-watcher

In the offical site of Elastic Watcher, they said

- Watcher is a plugin for Elasticsearch that provides alerting and notification based on changes in your data
- The relevant data or changes in data can be identified with a periodic Elasticsearch query

What I want is a function like Trigger of MySQL, that is when a record is updated, a action is triggered.

But I didn't find a example or document to address this use case, can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You define an [`input` of type `search`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/input.html#input-search) and using `body`, `indices` (mainly) you define which indices to look at (`indices`) and what is the actual query (`body`). If you need other settings, [there are many more things to configure](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/input.html#input-search). After this, you define a [condition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/condition.html) and an [action](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/actions.html) to complete the flow.

Make an attempt and create a watch. If you have difficulties, provide details of what you tried in a different SO post (you realize your current post is not appropriate for SO since you ask for complete code without you trying anything).

Comment: thanks for your reply Andrei, I will have a try and give a feedback to you~

Comment: after read the docs of watcher, i know what is input, trigger, condition, and action ,etc, but what i want is a function like Trigger of MySQL, that is when a record is updated, a action is triggered.. But it seems that the watcher cannot do it or maybe i still cannot got how to do it  from these docs..